# Why is the number of components in the torus link $T_{p,q}$ equal to $\gcd(p,q)$?

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology

I was not able to prove this by myself and also have not found any proof online. Since it is often stated as a fact, I assume it should not be a difficult statement to prove.

The definition of $T_{p,q}$ in this case is as follows:

Torus links are produced by choosing a pair of integers $p$ and $q$, with $p$ positive; forming a cylinder with $p$ strings running along it, twisting it up through “$q/p$ full twists” (the sign of $q$ determines the direction of twist) and gluing its ends together to form an unknotted torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The torus is irrelevant — one is only interested in the resulting link $T_{p,q}$ formed from the strands drawn on its surface.

This definition is taken from Roberts - Knotes.

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: How are you defining $T_{p,q}$? From one point of view, it's simply convention: if you have $p$ and $q$ coprime and want $n$ parallel $T_{p,q}$ torus knot components, then you can encode that as $T_{np,nq}$ since you can recover $n$ from $\operatorname{gcd}(np,nq)$. But from others it's something you'd need to prove.

Comment: @Kyle Miller I have added the definition I use in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see why there are $\gcd(p,q)$ strands? Look at the base at the bottom of the cylinder, where the strands are just dots, and number the dots from $0$ to $p-1$. If you take the $k$th dot and follow the strand until you reach the top of the cylinder, you come back at the bottom of the cylinder but at the $(k+q)$th dot. So we see there are $\gcd(p,q)$ strands.

We can rotate a strand on the cylinder around the axis of the cylinder (so that it stays on the cylinder) until we recover another strand. The surface covered in this way is $I × S^1$. This is one of the components. We can repeat this process $\gcd(p,q)$ times until we get back our original strand, and it gives the $\gcd(p,q)$ components of the torus.

Comment: Just to fill in the details in a particular way: if you go from the $k$th dot to the $(k+q)$th dot after going around once, then we can solve $nq\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ for $n$ to find how many times you have to go around to get back to where you started, and the least positive $n$ solving this is $p/\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)$. This is the number of dots taken up by one of the components, so $p/(p/\operatorname{gcd}(p,q))=\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)$ is how many components there are.

Comment: Yes. Another way of phrasing that is that the dots belonging to one strand are the cosets of the subgroup generated by $q$ in $ℤ/pℤ$. The reciprocal image of this subgroup by $ℤ ↠ ℤ/pℤ$ is the subgroup of $ℤ$ generated by $p$ and $q$, so it is $\gcd(p,q)ℤ$ and there are $\gcd(p,q)$ cosets.

Comment: An interesting fact is that the only non-intersecting loops on the torus are the $T_{p,q}$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime. It has to do with the Stern-Brocot tree: look at the torus as $[0,1]^2$ quotiented by the usual relation. An intersection-free loop on $^2$ is given by a sequence of choices: we start at $(0,0)$, we move up and right and then we have three possibilities: either we finish the loop by going to $(1,1)$, or we go to the right side, or we go to the top side. And we continue.

Comment: Each time we have a choice, we record it and it gives a bijection between some of the loops and the sequences of $0$s and $1$s. This is the Stern-Brocot enumeration of the pairs of coprime integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps!